# Changing ToolStripMenuItem  Enabled Property Based on Successful Login

Tags: vb.net, passwords, userid

What I've done so far . . .

```
Private Sub LogInToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles LogInToolStripMenuItem.Click

    Try
        If (txtAdminUserId.Text <> "admin" AndAlso txtMaintenacePassword.Text <> "1234") Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter the correct UserID and also verify your Pasword. ", "UserID and Password Error")
            txtAdminUserId.Select()
            txtAdminUserId.Focus()
            Return
        Else
            txtAdminUserId.Clear()
            txtMaintenacePassword.Clear()
            Dim frmGameMaintenanceX As New frmGameMaintenance() 'declare game order form
            Me.Visible = False
            frmGameMaintenanceX.Show() 'switch to order movie form
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Caught General Error") ' last attempt to catch an exception

    End Try
End Sub
```

Based on the requirements for a ToolStripMenuItem as follows verbatim from my instructor:

> “Add a maintenance menu with Log-in (enabled) as menu item. When the user successfully logs in (with admin and 1234 as the userid and password), disable the log-in menu item and make menu items Games, Platforms, Ratings, and Log-out visible. When the user logs out, enable the log-in menu item, hide the Games, Platforms, Ratings, and Log-out menu items.”
>   Let's keep it simple. Use an if statement to test if the user attempts to log in with the proper userid and password (defined as constants in your code).”

What is an efficient way to handle ToolStripMenuItem with very limited password requirements?  You have the click event from “Log-In”  but where would the maintenance user enter his userid and password smoothly?

Comment: Ackward pharasing of the question on my part.  What I've done will probably suffice . . . it just looks cludgey to me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code will suffice while I continue to learn . . .

```
Private Sub LogInToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles LogInToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Try
        If (txtAdminUserId.Text <> cstUsrId OrElse txtMaintenacePassword.Text <> cstPsswrd OrElse txtAdminUserId.Text.Length <> 5 OrElse txtMaintenacePassword.Text.Length <> 4) Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter the correct UserID and also verify your Pasword. ", "UserID and Password Error")
            txtAdminUserId.Select()
            txtAdminUserId.Focus()
            Return
        Else
            txtAdminUserId.Clear()
            txtMaintenacePassword.Clear()
            LogInToolStripMenuItem.Visible = False
            LogOutToolStripMenuItem.Visible = True
            LogOutToolStripMenuItem.Visible = True
            GameToolStripMenuItem.Visible = True
            GamesToolStripMenuItem.Visible = True
            PlatformToolStripMenuItem.Visible = True
            RatingsToolStripMenuItem.Visible = True
            LogInToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = False
            LogOutToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True
            LogOutToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True
            GameToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True
            GamesToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True
            PlatformToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True
            RatingsToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Caught General Error") ' last attempt to catch an exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following method in module and you can call it anywhere when you want to enable/disable ToolStripMenuItems

```
Public Sub SetAllMenuItems(ByRef menuStrip As MenuStrip, ByVal enable As Boolean)
        Dim c As ToolStripItem
        Dim t As ToolStripMenuItem
        For Each c In menuStrip.Items
            c.Enabled = enable
            If c.GetType Is GetType(ToolStripMenuItem) Then
                t = c
                SetAllMenuItems(t.DropDownItems, enable)
            End If
        Next
End Sub
Public Sub SetAllMenuItems(ByRef menus As ToolStripItemCollection, ByVal enable As Boolean)
        Dim c As ToolStripItem
        Dim t As ToolStripMenuItem
        For Each c In menus
            c.Enabled = enable
            If c.GetType Is GetType(ToolStripMenuItem) Then
                t = c
                SetAllMenuItems(t.DropDownItems, enable)
            End If
        Next
End Sub
```